# Should "hide ignored tags" be the default?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

The recent spate of Skyrim questions has made the home page unusable for people who aren't interested in the game.  Due to the nature of the gaming site (and since we're probably going to do more promotions like this), this probably won't be uncommon.

We already have the "ignored tags" feature, but by default that doesn't actually *hide* the questions, it just fades them out.  There's a user preference to hide ignored questions, but it's hard to find.

So should "hide ignored tags" be the default?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Just because you don't play Skyrim, it doesn't mean you shouldn't try and work with us in moderating the site even on such questions.  Also, hiding works everywhere, including search result pages. That can be changed, but as it is it leads to confusion.

Comment: @badp moderating seems like an odd case to optimize the home page for...99% of what people do on the site is not moderation

Comment: Well, moderation starts from editing. Even anonymous users can do that. :)

Comment: I wouldn't mind either way so much if there was an easier and more noticeable way to change it.

Comment: Of course, then you end up with a front page that's really short. Yesterday, my front page only had 8 questions on it.

Comment: @Powerlord we will also fix the front page so that it won't be empty

Comment: @DavidFullerton: In that case, yes! (Although I like spoiler on my ignore list, so maybe not if it's marked interesting too?)

Answer (score 8):

It should not be the default, rather when a users adds a tag to the ignored list for the first time (or the first time after the feature I am proposing is implemented) a little popup should appear to inform them that there is a "hide ignored tags" option in the preferences.

Comment: ah, interesting alternative since there doesn't seem to be much support for making it the default

Comment: @DavidFullerton Informing the user of options is usually better than changing defaults, especially ones that control important items like display of questions.

Comment: maybe...though "just give the user the option" can also lead to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora/44641#44641  I still think fading out questions is a weird behavior for something called "ignore", and any change would only affect new users - we could keep it at whatever the user has set if they already have ignored tags

Answer (score 6):

I would actually prefer the current behaviour of having "hide ignored tags" off by default, though I realize I'm probably in the minority.

If you're going to change the default, please make the option more easily accessible as well for those of us who will be turning it off.

Comment: I would also say the current default is fine **as long as** the option to change it is more accessible/obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be the default. I think "ignore" has an Internet-wide connotation of "do not show me", and we should follow that principle here. A novice user who clicks on "ignore" will probably expects these questions to simply disappear.

Comment: I agree with that, with the caveat that the "emtpy frontpage" problem should be solved in some way. Having a near-empty frontpage when ignoring a popular tag is also an unexpected result.

Comment: That could (and should) be solved by always returning a set maximum number of results per page, rather than returning a set number and _then_ hiding the ignored ones.

Answer (score 0):

When this question was posted, the options to change between 'grey out' and 'hide' ignored tags were hidden away in the profile settings somewhere. This is no longer the case.

These settings now appear directly on the 'Ignored Tags' box itself, making it easier to switch between them. Click the ignored tag box:

[image: Ignored Tags Box]

And you get this:

[image: Radio buttons for 'Hide' or 'Gray out' ignored questions]

While it's not quite what you ask for with regards to the feature request, it does solve the issue you mention about the settings to switch preferences being hard to find.